# MASM recursion simulating multiplication

Tags: recursion, assembly, masm

I am getting a stack overflow error at the position 'Call CalcProd' (within the function itself, not in main). Any idea why?

Here are relevant variable declarations:

```
Num1 DWORD 12
Num2 DWORD 7
Prod DWORD 0
```

Here is my function linkage and call in Main:

```
;----------------------CalcProd LINKAGE------------------
PUSH Num1
PUSH Num2
PUSH OFFSET Prod
CALL CalcProd
;--------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my function:

```
;-------------------------CalcProd-------------------------
;calculates the product of the Num1 * Num2
;e.g. CalcProd(5,3) = 5+5+5 = 15
;params: Num1 and Num2 are passed in on the stack
;output: the product is put into the Prod variable
;------------------------------------------------------------

CalcProd proc

    N1 EQU 16[ebp]
    N2 EQU 12[ebp]
    P EQU 8[ebp]

    ;necessary
    PUSH ebp
    MOV ebp,esp

    MOV ecx,N2
    ;if (Num2 == 0)
    CMP ecx,0
    JE baseCase

    ;else return CalcProd(Num1,Num2-1)
    DEC ecx
    ;PUSH ecx ; Num2-1
    MOV N2,ecx
    CALL CalcProd

    ;adds number to itself here
    MOV esi,P
    MOV eax,N1
    ADD [esi],eax

baseCase:
    MOV esp,ebp
    POP ebp
    ret 12

CalcProd endp

;the fix:
;else return CalcProd(Num1,Num2-1)
;DEC ecx
;PUSH Num1
;PUSH ecx
;PUSH OFFSET Prod
;CALL CalcProd
```

Comment: You are not passing any arguments in the recursive call. Also your whole code is unclear (and pointless of course).

Comment: Harsh, but thanks. I thought where I was pushing ecx was where I was passing the argument in.

Comment: Your `push ecx` is commented out so it doesn't do anything. Also, you need 2 parameters not 1.

Comment: @nhershy you aren't pushing `ecx`, it's commented out. Not only that but you have to push the other two parameters too.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You were all right, I wasn't pushing the other two parameters. Code works now. Put the fix at the bottom of the code.